# relay-modern FragmentContainer outside QueryRenderer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, relayjs, relaymodern

Is it possible? Can we use `FragmentContainer` outside a QueryRenderer? 
What I want to achieve:
I have a `RefetchContainer` with a `SectionList`. Every item inside each section is a `FragmentContainer`. When I select an item from a section, I want to open a new screen where I display a `FlatList` of these items. The data I pass from the `SectionList` on item select is a list of `FragmentContainer`. Thus I can't see the data so I need to use fragments for it. If I use just fragments inside the `FlatList` I get a missing environment from the `RelayFragmentContainer`. 
So I added a QueryRenderer as parent for the `FlatList` where I request the same single section once again. But this makes an extra `QueryRenderer` request. I want to display the data from the previous screen. 
At least I pass this list of `FragmentContainer` as cacheConfig and return it from the `fetchQuery` method but, the json differs from the response json hence it is not raw data but already `__fragments`, thus the `Relay` cannot parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to get some code examples in this question of what your components and fragments look like. That said, you might want to investigate using the `@mask` directive.

I've taken an example from the Relay documentation and included it here:

```
module.exports = createFragmentContainer(
  ({ user }) => ...,
  graphql`
    fragment Component_user on User {
      internUser {
        manager {
          ...Component_internUser @relay(mask: false)
        }
        .... on Employee {
          admins {
            ...Component_internUser @relay(mask: false)
          }
          reports {
            ...Component_internUser @relay(mask: false)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    fragment Component_internUser on InternUser {
      id
      name
    }
  `,
);
```

By using the `@mask` data included from a fragment will be available in the component that is hosting the fragment. Relay documentation about this is available here: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/relay-directives.html#relay-mask-boolean

Comment: Oh Thank you ! This is not 100% what was I looking for, but it serves the purpose more than I expected to achieve here! Thank you so much!